# Add donation check box only to customers from CA

Tags: wordpress, for-loop, if-statement, woocommerce

I am trying to set up a donation checkbox only for Canadian customers based on their input/past shipping address. The checkbox should display only if the shipping country is Canada. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'git_box' ); 
    function gift_box ( $checkout ) {
             echo '<div id="message_fields">';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'add_gift_box', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('add_gift_box form-row-wide'),

        'label'         => __('Add Donation to the site? ($2)'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' ));
        echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_add_gift_box' );
function woocommerce_add_gift_box() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('#add_gift_box').click(function(){
            jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
function woo_add_cart_fee( $cart ){
        if ( ! $_POST || ( is_admin() && ! is_ajax() ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
    } else {
        $post_data = $_POST; 
    }

    if (isset($post_data['add_gift_box'])) {
         $extracost = 2.65;
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Site Donation:', $extracost );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you tried a bit too simple ;-)
Here's my tested version. Show/Hide get's triggered on document load and on billing country change, then unchecks the checkbox in case the newly selected country is not CA.

1) Add the checkbox

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'add_donate_field' );
function add_donate_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_donate'] = array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'label' => 'Add Donation to the site? ($2)',
        'required' => false,
        'class' => array('donation form-row-wide hidden')
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

2) Add the Show hide + Ajax functions (style can go somewhere else, just added here so it works out of the box)

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_donate_field_js' );
function woocommerce_donate_field_js() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
        ?>
        <style> .donation.hidden { display: none; }</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){
                var donatefield = '.donation',
                    donatebox = 'input[name=order_donate]',
                    bc = 'select#billing_country',
                    donate_enabled_countries = ['CA'],
                    donate = '0';

                // Show/Hide the donate field
                function showHideDonate(){
                    if (jQuery.inArray( $(bc).val(), donate_enabled_countries) === -1){
                        if ( ! $(donatefield).hasClass('hidden') ) {
                            $(donatebox).prop('checked',false).trigger('change');
                            $(donatefield).addClass('hidden');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(donatefield).removeClass('hidden');
                    }
                }
                $(bc).change(showHideDonate);
                $(document).ready(showHideDonate);

                // Send donate field value to AJAX
                $('form.checkout').on('change', donatebox, function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { donate = '1'; } else { donate = '0'; }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                        data: {
                            'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
                            'donate': donate,
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

3) Get the AJAX data

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'checkout_donate_choice_set_session' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'checkout_donate_choice_set_session' );
function checkout_donate_choice_set_session() {
    if ( isset($_POST['donate']) ){
        $donate = sanitize_key( $_POST['donate'] );
        WC()->session->set('donate', $donate );
        echo json_encode( $donate );
    }
    die();
}
```

4) Update the cart

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woocommerce_donate_fee' );
function woocommerce_donate_fee( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    $donate = WC()->session->get( 'donate' );
    $donation = 2; // Donation amount
    $test = 0; // just for testing can be removed
    if ($donate === '1') {
        $cart->add_fee( __('Donation', 'woocommerce'), $donation );
    } else { // can be removed as well
        $cart->add_fee( __('No Donation', 'woocommerce'), $test );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is alrady included. When the checkbox gets hidden, it also triggers unchecking it. Note the above code is all for billing, not shipping country though, if you want to trigger it on shipping or both, you'll need to change the "bc = 'select#billing_country'" part of the JS.